# How to add new state name in checkout State/Province dropdown list?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3.3

How to add a new state name in the checkout  State/Province dropdown list?
we have used the Amasty_Chekout extension.

I want to add a new state name field, it is possible,

[image]

if it is possible in custom form?
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply add the data to DB table **directory_country_region** with
> country code please check the below screenshot.

[image]

> After adding the name in **directory_country_region** table add data
> in **directory_country_region_name** as per the below screenshot.

[image]

> After that, it will appear on the checkout page. please check the
> below screenshot.

[image]